# Kendo UI Window to center after a refresh of large content

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Using `MVC 4` I add a `blank window` and hide it. On a button click I call this javascript to get content and `center` the window:

```
        var win = $("#myWindow").data("kendoWindow");
        win.content("Loading...");
        win.refresh({
            url: "@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")",
            data: { userloginid: "AAA" }
        });
        win.center();
        win.open();
```

The content is `larger than a default window` so the `win.center()` calculation is off, putting the window too far down.

How do I get the window to **center** based on the content it got via the **refresh()** command.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem seems to be, that you center the window, and than, some time after that, the new content is finished loading.

In other words: The center is called before the window get's its new size through the loaded content.

To prevent this, you should bind to the **refresh** event of the window, and center in that.

Something along the lines (**beware: only register this event once**):

```
var win = $("#myWindow").data("kendoWindow");
win.bind("refresh", function() {
    win.center();
    win.open();
});
```